# How to execute code if a variable has a certain value?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a problem with my code. The language is python. I am trying to use an if statement to execute some code if a variable has a certain value.

```
op = 5

if(op = 5):
    print("op is 5!")
```

Every time I run this program, it gives me a syntax error. I have tried doing this instead;

```
op = 5

if op = 5:
    print("op is 5!")
```

But it still gives me the error. I am asking this question because I am doing a calculator project and need this.

Comment: You cannot have an assignment statement inin place of the Boolean condition of an `if` statement.

Comment: @Prune not technically true now that there are assignment expressions. i.e. walrus operator `:=`. *Edit:* Actually I guess you said statement so you are still correct

Comment: Make sure to include the _actual error message_ in question, formatted appropriately. In this case the `^` points to the exact part of the expression (unfortunately Python doesn't have a super clear diagnostic message which is certainly could in this case).

Comment: Yup -- I was incomplete from trying to stay simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=` is the assignment operator. You're looking for the equality check operator, `==`:

```
if op == 5:
    print("op is 5!")
```

Comment: @therealemg If this answers your question please mark it correct for future readers :)

Answer (score 1):

## You misspelled the equality check operator.

The equality check operator is `==`. You put the assignment operator, which is this: `=`.

The following code will return a `SyntaxError`:

```py
foo = input('Enter the value of foo: ')
if foo = '5':
    print('foo is equal to 5!')
else:
    print('foo is not equal to 5!')
```

But this won't:

```py
foo = input('Enter the value of foo: ')
if foo == '5':
    print('foo is equal to 5!')
else:
    print('foo is not equal to 5!')
```

You just need to change the operator in the if statement to `==`.

Answer (score 1):

For comparison we used double equal sign ==

Not single

```
if op == 5:
    print("op is 5!")
```